# Excel cell from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel

Excel 07. I have two excel spreadsheets. Sheet1 has a few cells on it that I would like to be populated with a few cells from sheet2. This I want sheet1 to replicate this about 400 times for all employees in the agency.

Here is the example.

Sheet 1

Person name  number1  number 2 number 3
Cell         cell     cell     cell

Sheet 2 Information sheet.
Person name   number1 Number2   number3
Jim           23      32        54
Sally         25      22        53

End result

Sheet 3
Person name    number1   number2 number3
Jim            23        32      54

Sheet 4
Person name number1 number2 number3
sally       25      22      53

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Hmm...is the specifically programming related or would http://superuser.com perhaps be a better place for this question?

Comment: Made sense to me; That the biggest problem with Stack Overflow. So quick to bash the question instead of trying to help...

Answer (score 2):

Look at VLookup or HLookup functions. It's basically a join between sheets on a cell value.